# how to generate QR code with logo inside using objective C

Tags: ios, qr-code

I want to create a QR code with Logo/image inside to make it unique, i have tried several code but nothing is working for example https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=qr+code+with+logo+for+ios&sa=N&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=654&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwj8yNDrhcLSAhVIDxoKHRlzCLc4ChCwBAge#imgrc=zbZTeyTrkFArdM:

Comment: I'm pretty sure that putting a logo inside a QR code will render it unreadable. Thus, you can't have a QR code with a logo in it that can still be scanned.

Comment: @DuncanC There are many providers that provide a QR code with a little logo in the middle. So yes it is possible, but still ask for off-site resource is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error correction mechanism in QR codes, so it should be readable, obviously so long as you don't use to much space. With High Quality encoding, up to 30% of the code words can be restored. 
Meaning you can use up to 30% - theoretically-  of the surface for something else, that is a logo.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction

You can use any available QR code source, I'm using this one, works pretty well
https://github.com/moqod/ios-qr-code-encoder

You need to make sure that you use the right encoding quality.